# Why is my buffer overflow attempt segfaulting?

Tags: c, linux, security, exploit

I'm wondering why a buffer overflow exploit isn't working in a particular scenario. As of now the overflow I am working on can redirect the return address, and when I focus on a piece of memory say `<_fini>` the program will exit without performing anything else that comes after the function. The strange thing is when I attempt to redirect the memory to an environment variable. For some reason this does not work due to a segmentation fault. Anyone have any ideas why this is?

Here is the code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func(char *buff){  
    char buffer[5];
    strcpy(buffer, buff);
    printf("%s\n", buffer);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    func(argv[1]);
    printf("I'm done!\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Anything from access violation to you doing something else wrong -- we need to see what your code looks like

Comment: gdb and valgrind are your friends, use them!

Comment: He can't gdb or valgrind with an environment variable and try a B.O.: those will move the program's memory in some "safe" zone so the overflow will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a little piece on buffer overflows using environment variables which may be of some service to you:  http://pinkmist.dyndns.org:8080/2012/04/24/basic-stack-overflow/.  There are any number of things that could be causing your problem.  I have to ask, have you tried writing a buffer overflow without environment variables yet?  I've found using environment variables makes things a lot easier, but its probably a good learning exercise that will really help you understand why these things work.  Another few things to think about which I mention above are: ASLR and stack smashing protection on GCC.  Either of these things could really put a damper on your day.  Make sure you have disabled ASLR and stack smashing protection(both are on by default in any modern distribution).

Answer (score 0):

You are possibly trying to exploit a binary on a system that has Data Execution Prevention (DEP). This would mean the environment area, along with pretty much everything else that's not code from the binary and its libraries, will be located in memory pages marked as not executable - causing a segmentation fault when you try to execute anything in them.

Either remove the protections (the exact procedure will depend on the operating system) or limit yourself to memory addresses marked as executable.